# Format string with * operator and multiple variables

Tags: python

I've encountered the following problem: I want to fill a string with variables in the following way:

```
myList = [ 1000, 2000 ]
extra = "$"
myString = "{listItem}{extra} {listItem}{extra}".format(listItem = *myList, extra = extra)
```

I'm encountering the error Invalid Syntax at the * operator. I guess it is because format is taking two arguments instead of one. If I remove the {extra}-tag completely and only the name `listItem` like so

```
myString = "{} {}".format(*myList)
```

the code works. What do I need to change?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Try `myString = "{}{extra} {}{extra}".format(*myList, extra=extra)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a generator to format ieach list element, and the join them together.

```
myString = " ".join(f"{listItem}{extra}" for listItem in myList)
```